# Obtener el nombre de la celda a partir del índice de filas y columnas en LibreOffice Calc

Tags: vba, libreoffice-calc

Tengo un código que, al pulsar un botón, coge valores uno a uno de la columna de una hoja llamada `REPARTITION PIECES`, crea una nueva pestaña llamada `FICHE INVENTAIRE` y los envía por valor a esa pestaña.

Me gustaría enviar la referencia de la celda para que luego cambie automáticamente en la `FICHE INVENTAIRE` cuando cambie la `REPARTITION PIECES`.

Por ejemplo, cuando cambie la celda A2 en `REPARTITION PIECES` tendría = `REPARTITION PIECES`$A$2 en la celda correspondiente en `FICHE INVENTAIRE`.

Esta es la versión anterior:

```
          For n = 1 To ligs + 1
              y = Mid(celu(n), 6)
              y = y - 1
              nombre = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(col, y).String
              If nombre <> "" Then
                 li = li + 1
                 code = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(1, y).String
                 clair = thisComponent.Sheets.getByName("REPARTITION PIECES").getCellByPosition(2, y).String

thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D, li-l).String = Date()
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+1, li-l).String = code
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+2, li-l).String = clair
thisComponent.Sheets.getByName(onglet).getCellByPosition(D+5, li-l).String = nombre
                 ' If li > 22 And D = 0 Then
                 '     D = 6
                 '     l = 22
                 ' End If
                 If strcomp(onglet, "FICHE INVENTAIRE") = 0 Then
                      borne = 30
                  Else
                      borne = 19
                  End If

                 If (li - l) >= borne Then
                      If strcomp(onglet, "FICHE INVENTAIRE") = 0 Then
                          li = 9
                      Else
                          li = 3
                      End If
                      If D = 0 Then
                          D = D + 6
                      Else
                          onglet = "VERSO FICHE INVENTAIRE"
                          li = 3
                          D = 0
                      End If
                  End If

              End If
         Next n
```